# Finding the maximum of quadratic forms

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms

For some real vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^p$ and $p \times p$ positive definite real matrices $A_1, A_2, \dots, A _n$, consider another vector of quadratic forms:

$$
(x^\top A_1 x, \dots, x^\top A_n x).
$$

I am trying the get the maximum element of the $n$ quadratic forms. Once I have the maximum element, I do not need the rest. Since I have to repeat the computation many times with different $x$, I have been thinking about fast and efficient ways to achieve this goal.

Is there a way to find the maximum without computing all of them? I tried to diagonalize the matrices to use the eigenvalues but don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Is the real vector $x$ freely sampled from the whole $p$ dimensional spaces? Is it a variable to be maximize over? 

Or you want the max element from the quadratic form vector for each of the $x$ you have?

Comment: @BinxuWang王彬旭 $x$ will be sampled from a multivariate normal distribution with mean 0 and some fixed positive definite covariance matrix. Once $x$ is sampled and fixed, there is nothing random any more and I need to get the maximum of the quadratic forms. Then I repeat this process with a new $x$ with the same $A_1, \dots, A_n$.